# Loss of data when passing as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to upload multiple files with ajax. This input field is placed in a multipart/form-data form:

```
<input type="file" id="upload" accept="image/jpeg" name="file[]" multiple >
```

In this code, the size of the files array becomes undefined in the add_image function. Why?

---

```
function add_image(images, i) {
    var image = images.item(i);
    var total = images.lenght;
    console.log(total);
    if (i < total) {
        $.ajax({
            ...
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#upload').on('change', function () {
        console.log(this.files.length);
        add_image(this.files, 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: You have a typo in line 3 lenght insted of length.

Comment: be sure to tell us if the typo fixes the problem.

Comment: Yeah, it did solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in line 3 `lenght` instead of `length`.